# JavaScript if statement help needed

Tags: javascript, jquery, if-statement, html-helper

I'm using JavaScript to achieve a preview box when hovering over a list. I'll show you my code and then a live website on how it works, then I will say the problem.

HTML

```
<div id="content">

<div id="theDiv"><h1>Custom </h1></div>

<div id="theDiv1"><h1>Custom One</h1> </div>

<div id="theDiv2"><h1>Custom Two</h1></div>

<div id="theDiv3"><h1>Custom Three</h1></div>

<div id="theDiv4"><h1>Custom Four</h1></div>

<div id="theDiv5"><h1>Custom Five</h1></div>

<div id="theDiv6"><h1>Custom Six</h1></div>

<div id="theDiv7"><h1>Custom Seven</h1></div>


<ul id="nav">
  <li><a href="#"><b>Austria ></b></a> <br/>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" class="theLink">Factsheet </a></li><br/>
      <li><a href="#" class="theLink1">Stylesheet </a></li><br/>
      <li><a href="#" class="theLink2">References </a></li><br/>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#"><b>Switzerland ></b></a> <br/>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" class="theLinka">Factsheet </a></li><br/>
      <li><a href="#" class="theLinka1">Stylesheet </a></li><br/>
      <li><a href="#" class="theLinka2">References </a></li><br/>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#"><b>Explanation Page ></b></a> <br/>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#" class="theLinkb">Stylesheet </a></li><br/>
      <li><a href="#" class="theLinkb1">References </a></li><br/>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>



        </div>
```

CSS

```
ul {
    padding-left:10px;
    list-style: none;
    width:150px;
}


ul li {
    position: relative;
    left:10px;
    width:148px;
}

li ul {
    position: relative;
    display:none;
}
/* Styles for Menu Items */
ul li a {
    display:block;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height:2em;
    height:2em; 
    padding:0 5px;
    color:#666;
}
a:hover {color:#999;}
li ul li {width:139px; }
li.on ul { display:block; }
li.off ul{display:none; }
.linkhover:hover {text-decoration:underline; }
.linkxp:hover {text-decoration:underline; }

#theDiv, #theDiv1, #theDiv2, #theDiv3, #theDiv4, #theDiv5, #theDiv6, #theDiv7, #theDiv8 {
    padding:10px;
    float:right;
    margin:0px 50px 0 0;
    width:300px;
    height:500px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    display:none;
}
```

JavaScript

```
$(window).load(function(){
 $(".theLink").hover(
        function () {
            $("#theDiv").fadeIn();
        },
        function () {
            $("#theDiv").fadeOut();
        }
    );
});

$(window).load(function(){
 $(".theLink1").hover(
        function () {
            $("#theDiv1").fadeIn();
        },
        function () {
            $("#theDiv1").fadeOut();
        }
    );
});

$(window).load(function(){
 $(".theLink2").hover(
        function () {
            $("#theDiv2").fadeIn();
        },
        function () {
            $("#theDiv2").fadeOut();
        }
    );
});

$(window).load(function(){
 $(".theLinka").hover(
        function () {
            $("#theDiv3").fadeIn();
        },
        function () {
            $("#theDiv3").fadeOut();
        }
    );
});

$(window).load(function(){
 $(".theLinka1").hover(
        function () {
            $("#theDiv4").fadeIn();
        },
        function () {
            $("#theDiv4").fadeOut();
        }
    );
});

$(window).load(function(){
 $(".theLinka2").hover(
        function () {
            $("#theDiv5").fadeIn();
        },
        function () {
            $("#theDiv5").fadeOut();
        }
    );
});

$(window).load(function(){
 $(".theLinkb").hover(
        function () {
            $("#theDiv6").fadeIn();
        },
        function () {
            $("#theDiv6").fadeOut();
        }
    );
});

$(window).load(function(){
 $(".theLinkb1").hover(
        function () {
            $("#theDiv7").fadeIn();
        },
        function () {
            $("#theDiv7").fadeOut();
        }
    );
});
```

Here is a link to a live view;
http://tubebackgrounds.co.uk/uni/demo/explanation.html#

As you can see, if you hover over the list style too quickly when they are being displayed, the other ones show up. I'm wondering if it is possible to use an if statement so only one

```
$(window).load(function(){
 $(".theLink").hover(
        function () {
            $("#theDiv").fadeIn();
        },
        function () {
            $("#theDiv").fadeOut();
        }
    );
});
```

can be enabled at once? Or maybe a way to make the fadeIn and fadeOut quicker.

Comment: 8 questions asked and not a single accepted answer is really poor form.

Comment: You should learn about loops.

Comment: I think I have accepted some answers. I'm sorry about that, I didn't know I needed too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

part of the issue is just your css. you have each of your divs (#theDiv, #theDiv1, #theDiv2, etc...) floated next to each other. so when you hide one, the next one will pop up in its place. if you set their display propety to display:block you will set what I am saying. What you really want is those divs to be stacked one on top of another, like a deck of cards, then fade then in and out. To achieve this try adding this css:

```
#content { 
   position:relative;
} 
#theDiv, #theDiv1, #theDiv2, #theDiv3, #theDiv4,#theDiv5, #theDiv6, #theDiv7, #theDiv8 {
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    display: none;
    height: 500px;
    margin: 0 50px 0 0;
    padding: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    width: 300px;
}
```

now you javascript should work fine. you could make the javascript a bit nicer by using @beerwin suggestion and using a callback. that way the div fading in will only fadin once the previous one has faded out

Answer (score 0):

Use callback function:

```
$(window).load(function(){
  $(".theLink").hover(
    function () {
        $("#theDiv").fadeOut(function(){
            $("#theDiv1").fadeIn();
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: I am pretty sure this is not going to fix the problem. Well the problem is bigger than just the fading

Comment: @Huangism: I see that the OP is showing the next div before hiding the  previous one, that's why both are appearing at the same time. My code is an example, created by using his.

Comment: you do know that you are fading out then fading in the exact same element

Comment: I can't seem to get this to work. I changed theDiv names around for each fadein/out but it won't see to fade out.

Comment: @John: Please see my example in the answer (you overlooked the callback). You must fade out the previous div before fading in the nex one.

Comment: By the way, i just noticed, that you're showing/hiding the same div when hovering the link. What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want to accomplish a live view box for each of my links in the list, but they all need to be different.